# C: free memory allocated to a struct doesn't work

Tags: c, pointers, struct, free

I am writing a ring buffer with C.
I am stuck on freeing the memory in the end.
The code compiles well, but the result shows `circBuf_free` function fails to free the allocated memory.
The relevant codes are:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h> //memcpy

#define kNumPointsInMyBuffer 16 
#define initialSize 10


typedef struct CircBuf_t //struct name CircBuf_t
{
    uint32_t *buffer;
    int head; // keep track the newest data
    int tail; // keep track the oldest data
    int maxLen; // maximum number of items in the buffer
}circBuf_t; //type name circBuf_t


 // initialize the circular buffer
void circBuf_init(circBuf_t *c, const int maxLen, int sz)
{
    c->buffer = malloc(maxLen * sz);
    c->maxLen = maxLen;
    if(c->buffer == NULL)
    printf("Buffer initialization fails\n");
    c->head = 0;
    c->tail = 0;
}

/* free the memory, free c->buffer first, then c*/
void circBuf_free(circBuf_t *c){
    free(c->buffer);
    free(c);
}


int main(){
// initilize ring Buffer    
const int maxLen = kNumPointsInMyBuffer;

// original src
int src[1024] = {};
int i =0;
for(i=0; i<1024; i++){
    src[i] = i;
}

//data
uint32_t data[1024];    
memcpy(data, src, 1024);

printf("\nThe size of the uint32_t data array is %lu\n", sizeof(data));
int sz = sizeof(*data);

circBuf_t *cb;
cb = malloc(sizeof(circBuf_t));
circBuf_init(cb, maxLen, sz);



assert(cb);
printf("cb's value is %p\n", cb);
circBuf_free(cb);
printf("cb's value is %p\n", cb);
assert(!cb);

return 0;
}
```

Result:

> cb's value is 0x1266010
>
> cb's value is 0x1266010
>
> a.out: sample.c:73: main: Assertion `!cb' failed.
>
> Aborted (core dumped)

The address of the pointer to the structure is the same.

Need help!

Comment: It is expected to be the same. Freeing memory only frees memory, it does not modify any of your variables.

Comment: @molbdnilo thanks. But if so, how I can have an evidence that the free function has worked?

Answer (score 1):

> When you call free, the memory pointed to by the passed pointer is
>   freed, but the value of the pointer in the caller probably remains
>   unchanged, because C's pass-by-value semantics mean that called
>   functions never permanently change the values of their arguments. (See
>   also question 4.8.)
>
> A pointer value which has been freed is, strictly speaking, invalid,
>   and any use of it, even if it is not dereferenced (i.e. even if the
>   use of it is a seemingly innocuous assignment or comparison), can
>   theoretically lead to trouble. (We can probably assume that as a
>   quality of implementation issue, most implementations will not go out
>   of their way to generate exceptions for innocuous uses of invalid
>   pointers, but the Standard is clear in saying that nothing is
>   guaranteed, and there are system architectures for which such
>   exceptions would be quite natural.)
>
> When pointer variables (or fields within structures) are repeatedly
>   allocated and freed within a program, it is often useful to set them
>   to NULL immediately after freeing them, to explicitly record their
>   state.

Source : 
http://c-faq.com/malloc/ptrafterfree.html

Comment: thanks a lot! so the value of the pointer is unchanged, but the memory has been released. This just doesn't set my mind at ease.